# Custom HealthIndicator not registered when autowiring other beans

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to implement a custom actuator HealthIndicator to show a downstream API status, but autowiring a RestTemplate results in the HealthIndicator not showing up in the details at all.

Im using `spring-boot-starter-actuator` version `2.1.4.RELEASE`

This code which doesn't include an autowired component works and appears in the list of details under /actuator/health

```java
@Component
public class ApiHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up()
            .build();
    }
}
```

Response from /actuator/health:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "api": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 253883043840,
                "free": 75249156096,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as I add an autowired RestTemplate, the whole healthindicator isnt registered, neither is any exception thrown:

```java
@Component
public class ApiHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private RestTemplate apiRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDefaultPegaRestTemplate(RestTemplate apiRestTemplate){
        this.apiRestTemplate = apiRestTemplate;
        System.out.println("No exception thrown"); 
        //Breakpoint here also reveals RestTemplate is not null and autowired correctly
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        // Breakpoint here is never reached
        return Health.up()
            .build();
    }
}
```

Response from /actuator/health:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 253883043840,
                "free": 75249156096,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out why the HealthIndicator is completely ignored in this case even after the autowiring passes successfully.